# object not locked by thread before notify()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Iam making app for listening .mp3 words in greek language so i have mediaplayer and after lets say 1000ms it should display next word depends on .mp3 file so i have 3 functions play, pause and stop.. I need to pause thread and then continue when it ends. In my thread is not working pause method by calling notify i simply dont know how to lock object before calling notify().. Here is my Code i would be rly glad for every help..

```
   class MyinnerThread implements Runnable  {
    String name;
    Thread tr;
    boolean suspendFlag;
    int i = 0;

    MyinnerThread(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        tr = new Thread(this, name);
        suspendFlag = false;
        tr.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(i == 0){tv1.setText("trhead1");}
                    if(i == 1){tv2.setText("trhead2");}
                    if(i == 2){tv3.setText("trhead3");}
                    if(i == 3){tv4.setText("trhead4");}
                    if(i == 4){tv5.setText("trhead5");}
                    if(i == 5){tv6.setText("trhead6");}
                    if(i == 6){tv7.setText("trhead7");}
                    if(i == 7){tv8.setText("trhead8");}

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(800);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    synchronized(this) {
                        while(suspendFlag) {
                            try {
                                tr.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(200);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
    }
    void mysuspend() {
        suspendFlag = true;
    }

    synchronized void myresume() {
        suspendFlag = false;
        tr.notify();
}
```

}

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.play:
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

                t.mysuspend();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.start();

                if(runningThread){
                    t.myresume();
                }

                if(!runningThread){
                    runningThread = true;

                    t = new MyinnerThread("name");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.stop:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp.release();

            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            t = null;

            runningThread = false;

            setPlayer();
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the object you are synchronizing on? Is it MyinnerThread? Or is it its 'tr' member? You have to pick one and stick with it. You can't lock one and notify the other -- that makes no sense.

Comment: i working with this first time and did this so far.. iam not sure how to synchronize i have Global variable MyinnerThread(t) which is created you click on play button.. and in MyinnerThread class iam creating thread(tr) and i think i sychronazing (tr)... Please can you somehow help me get this code work and where should i repair it? iam strugling with this whole day...

Comment: Pick an object to synchronize on. If you're going to notify MyinnerThread, then synchronize on MyinnerThread. You've just split it across two objects and you can't do that. You must synchronize on the same object you notify and wait for.

Comment: so i make Global variable Object someObject = new Object(); and then everywhere in synchronize i put this object ?

Comment: You can do that if you want.

Comment: IT WORKS !!!!!!!! god bless you iam going to sleep

Comment: please i have still another problem i want to update textview every 1000ms but with this code it doesnt work.. only first textview is updated and then nothing..